# How do i align using list style?

Tags: css, alignment

Hey i'm trying to align things next to each other and under each other

Here is the css I'm using.

```
/* title styles */
#wpp-post-title {
 float:right;
 width:100px 

 }

 /* thumbnail styles */
 #wpp-thumbnail {
    float:left;
    width:80px;
 }
```

It shows up like this

[image]

but i want it to show like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of ids and look at clear property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

**jsFiddle demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vPvbn/

**CSS**:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0 85px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li style="background: url(http://i.imgur.com/9M7yb.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-right: 10px;">LEAKED: The Winner of RuPaul's Drag Race Season 4 Is...</li>
    <li  style="background: url(http://i.imgur.com/eJxiy.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-right: 10px;">WATCH: Rihanna's 'Battlefield' Movie Trailer.</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* title styles */
#wpp-post-title {
 width:100px 
 display: inline-block;
 .display: inline;
 .zoom:1;

 }

 /* thumbnail styles */
 #wpp-thumbnail {
     display: inline-block;
     .display: inline;
     .zoom:1;
    width:80px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, I can only guess, but my best guess would be to add the following style to your CSS:

```
/* You will probably need to change "li" to something more specific, lest it
   break your existing list styles. */
li {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will force the list item to wrap itself around your floated bits. Elements that are floated do not change the height of the parent container, so because everything inside the `<li>` is floated, your `<li>` element has a height of 0px, and you get the weird behaviour that you're seeing. `overflow: hidden` fixes this by forcing the `<li>` to acknowledge the height of `#wpp-thumbnail` and `#wpp-post-title`.

Answer (score 0):

Giving `#wpp-post-title` a height that is equal to your thumbnail should solve the problem, at the moment the browser is automatically determining the height of the div based on the text inside it.

Also, make sure both divs are given `display: inline-block` property